# Android studio: "error in opening zip files" "Gradle dependency cache may be corrupt"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I have a project in Android Studio that was working fine until yesterday, when it failed to compile and gave me the error depicted in the shots below.

I checked similar SO questions and deleted the .gradle directory then 'Sync project with gradle files' but the error remains and my project would not compile. I used the same version of gradle in another project and it compiles. The only difference is the one that failed to compile has volley of which build.gradle I have attached. I also attached my gradle-wrapper.properties screen shot.
[image]
[image]

I also have tried to clean, rebuild, and Invalidate cach/Restart but none worked. Can someone point me what is wrong?
[image]
[image]

This is part of the error log I thought would indicate where my problem is.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLookupException: Could not configure services using ConnectionScopeServices.configure().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:222)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:316)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.build(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.initializeServices(DefaultConnection.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.configure(DefaultConnection.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.configure(AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type DefaultClassLoaderRegistry using GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:741)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:695)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:216)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:316)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$1.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:297)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConnectionScopeServices.configure(ConnectionScopeServices.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:220)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModuleProperties(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:189)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.module(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.module(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultPluginModuleRegistry.getPluginModules(DefaultPluginModuleRegistry.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DynamicModulesClassPathProvider.findClassPath(DynamicModulesClassPathProvider.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.<init>(DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry(GlobalScopeServices.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:739)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModuleProperties(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:177)
    ... 53 more
2016-03-24 23:12:08,408 [23405204]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo1.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit1.gradle] 
2016-03-24 23:12:08,829 [23405625]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:360)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Comment: Clean the project & restart you android studio

Comment: Tried that multiple times but no it didn't work for me.

Comment: Clean the Project and restart Your System... or you need re-download your Dependencies...

Comment: Do you mean delete all the dependencies?

Comment: Is there a problem with Gradle installation, see the Exception `"org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8'"`. Try to `Invalidate Caches and Restart (Menu File)` or check if there is a gradle folder.

Comment: @EAA that is one of the things I tried first. It didn't work. FYI I have installed Android Studio long time ago. The error just happened out of nothing, I have never installed anything. It is a very frustrating experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my updates channel from stable to dev and Android Studio asked me to download updates which I did. Now the error is gone. I would really like to know what triggered that error. I wish the docs were more complete and include a section to ask this type of issues since this is not an issue caused by a developer's end.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:
   "**gradle-wrapper.properties**":
"*distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip*"

“**build.gradle（in your root projects gradle-dependence）**”:
"* classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'*"